# SCSS returns black

Tags: css, sass

I have some scss. Which is returning `$darkBlue` as black:

```
$blue: #62a8cf;
$darkBlue: darken($blue, 60%);
body {background-color:$darkBlue;}
```

I have also tried

```
$blue: #62a8cf;
$darkBlue: darken(#62a8cf, 60%);
body {background-color:$darkBlue;}
```

As well as:

```
$blue: #62a8cf;
body {background-color:darken(#62a8cf, 60%);}
```

All of them return darkGreen as black... my command line is not returning any errors, what am I doing wrong? Thank you!

ps. [here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajikanfan/9yjrp2j8/)

Comment: Reduce the % value. Ex:  darken(#62a8cf, 10%)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`black` is the correct value.

Take the following SCSS :

```
$blue: #62a8cf;
body {background-color:darken(#62a8cf, 50%);}
```

That produces this CSS :

```
body {
  background-color: #0c1d26;
}
```

That's already pretty close to `black`.

Now, take the following SCSS :

```
$blue: #62a8cf;
body {background-color:darken(#62a8cf, 59%);}
```

That produces the following CSS :

```
body {
  background-color: #010203;
}
```

That's about as close to `black` as it gets without actually being `black`, so it makes sense that anything above `59%` would produce `black`.

Comment: oh duh! I knew it had to be painfully obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `darken`, I prefer to use Sass's `scale-color` function. This will give you a lot for flexibility of making a given color lighter or darker. What this function will try to do is increase or decrease the lightness of a color while taking into consideration the lightness the color currently is.

See the returned values on your example using darken vs. scale-color

```
// Global blue
$blue: #62a8cf;

// Darken blue - Returns #000000
$darkBlue: darken($blue, 60%);

// Scale-color blue - Returns #1d465d
$darkBlue: scale-color($blue, $lightness: -60%);
```

This function is very useful for fine tuning. Here is a snippet from [Sass docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#scale_color-instance_method) explaining how it works

> For example, the lightness of a color can be anywhere between 0% and 100%. If scale-color($color, $lightness: 40%) is called, the resulting color’s lightness will be 40% of the way between its original lightness and 100. If scale-color($color, $lightness: -40%) is called instead, the lightness will be 40% of the way between the original and 0.

With this in mind, you won't receive black as the value of scale-color unless you have put `scale-color($blue, $lightness: -100%)`, even at -99% you get #010202 as the returned value.

Comment: Awesome answer man! Thanks @maxinacube, I will make a mental note of it

Answer (score 1):

The `darken` function simply caps the color at black. `darken(#62a8cf, 60%)` would result in a color that is equal to or deeper than black, so it's capped at `#000000`. Try `darken(#62a8cf, 30%)` - this results in a the color `#245774`.

---

**How does `darken` work?**

`darken` takes the lightness of a color. In this case, the lightness of `#62a8cf` is exactly 60, so decreasing that by 60 results in a lightness of 0, which is the color black.